# http chunked file transfer in netty finished immediately

Tags: kotlin, netty, chunked-encoding

I'm writing a http file server with downloading file in multiple thread with `netty`. When using only `HttpServerCodec()`, everything works perfect but OOM: direct buffer memory error. Then I turn to the `ChunkedWriteHandler()` handler.

But the problem is, the browser(new Edge) either say 'can't download file' or download a file with zero size. I have no idea about this and need help, please.

The log show that the transfer process complete immediately without any time cost.

```
[main] INFO Main - Pick up path C:/Temp
[main] INFO dd.oliver.htp.HtpServer - Server start at 2333
[nioEventLoopGroup-3-1] INFO dd.oliver.htp.RequestHandler - Request C:/Temp/d.test.oliverdd
[nioEventLoopGroup-3-1] INFO dd.oliver.htp.RequestHandler - [id: 0xe5ce2ec6, L:/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:2333 - R:/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:63040] Transfer complete.
```

here is my code, which is referring [netty example](https://github.com/netty/netty/blob/79a7c157a3e122872321844b73c4881e412dba77/example/src/main/java/io/netty/example/http/file/HttpStaticFileServerHandler.java#L418).

This is ChannelInitializer:

```kotlin
class HtpChannelInitializer(val basePath: String) : ChannelInitializer<SocketChannel>() {
    override fun initChannel(ch: SocketChannel) {
        ch.pipeline().addLast("HttpCodec", HttpServerCodec())
        ch.pipeline().addLast("HttpAggregator", HttpObjectAggregator(65536))
        ch.pipeline().addLast("HttpChunked", ChunkedWriteHandler())
        ch.pipeline().addLast("RequestHandle", RequestHandler(basePath))
    }
}
```

This is RequestHandler:

```kotlin
import io.netty.channel.*
import io.netty.handler.codec.http.*
import io.netty.handler.codec.http.HttpVersion.HTTP_1_0
import io.netty.handler.stream.ChunkedFile
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory
import java.io.File
import java.io.RandomAccessFile


private val logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(RequestHandler::class.java)

class RequestHandler_test(val basePath: String) : SimpleChannelInboundHandler<HttpRequest>() {
    ...

    override fun channelReadComplete(ctx: ChannelHandlerContext) {
        ctx.flush()
    }

    override fun channelRead0(ctx: ChannelHandlerContext, msg: HttpRequest) {
        val path = basePath + msg.uri() // msg.uri() example: / or /a/b or /a/b/c.txt
        logger.info("Request $path")
        val file = File(path)
        if (file.isFile) {
            val rfile = RandomAccessFile(file, "r")
            // Line
            val response = DefaultFullHttpResponse(HttpVersion.HTTP_1_1, HttpResponseStatus.OK)
            // Headers
            response.headers().set("Accept-Ranges", "bytes")
            response.headers().set("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=\"${file.name}\"")
            response.headers().set("Content-Type", "application/octet-stream")
            response.headers().set("Content-Length", "${rfile.length()}")
            if (!(msg.headers().contains("Connection") && msg.headers().get("Connection") == "keep-alive")) {
                response.headers().set(HttpHeaderNames.CONNECTION, HttpHeaderValues.CLOSE);
            } else if (msg.protocolVersion() == HTTP_1_0) {
                response.headers().set(HttpHeaderNames.CONNECTION, HttpHeaderValues.KEEP_ALIVE);
            }
            // Content
//                    response.content().writeBytes(rfile.channel, 0L, rfile.length().toInt())
//                    ctx.writeAndFlush(response).addListener(ChannelFutureListener.CLOSE)
            ctx.write(response)
            val sendFileFuture = ctx.write(
                HttpChunkedInput(ChunkedFile(rfile, 0, rfile.length(), 8192)),
                ctx.newProgressivePromise()
            )
            sendFileFuture.addListener(object : ChannelProgressiveFutureListener {
                override fun operationProgressed(
                    future: ChannelProgressiveFuture,
                    progress: Long,
                    total: Long
                ) {
                    if (total < 0) { // total unknown
                        logger.info(future.channel().toString() + " Transfer progress: " + progress)
                    } else {
                        logger.info(
                            future.channel().toString() + " Transfer progress: " + progress + " / " + total
                        )
                    }
                }

                override fun operationComplete(future: ChannelProgressiveFuture) {
                    logger.info(future.channel().toString() + " Transfer complete.")
                }
            })
            if (!(msg.headers().contains("Connection") && msg.headers().get("Connection") == "close")) {
                sendFileFuture.addListener(ChannelFutureListener.CLOSE)
            }
        }
    }

...
}
```

Comment: Any chance you could reduce this down to something much smaller that demonstrates the problem?  Sometimes, the act of doing this will lead to you figuring out the problem yourself.  If not, then you'll have a much better chance that someone will help you if you can give a smaller example.

Comment: Thanks @Steve. I have modified the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it! [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38517044/13760009) post has encountered the same question. It's `DefaultFullHttpResponse` which makes it wrong and everything will be right when change to `DefaultHttpResponse`.